# Find next element in Katalon

Tags: automated-tests, katalon-studio

How do I get the element next to currently selected element?

So my scenario is I open a page and click some button to load a table. When I click on the header of any column in the table it sorts and adds an image next to it. I have a locator for the header link. Problem is as it's old code it does not have id and that header link is in a td tag without any id or class. All it contains is a column name with a link. I want to make sure when I click that link image with sorting symbol appears next to it.

```
<td>
   <a>Column Header</a>
</td>
```

Click on the column header and it changes to :

```
<td>
   <a>Column Header</a>
   &nbsp; <img src="sorting icon url" />
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done through something called XPath axes , refer this link
http://learn-automation.com/how-to-write-dynamic-xpath-in-selenium/
the following methodologies work in katalon as well , you will have to make an object and give the xpath of that object.

for your query xpath could be ://div[@class='xyz']/following-sibling::*

Answer (score 0):

Let us asume that the button is uniquely identified by css selector `'td a'`. Then your script could be something like

```
TestObject button = new TestObject().addProperty('css', ConditionType.EQUALS, 'td a')
WebUI.click(button)
TestObject button2 = new TestObject().addProperty('css', ConditionType.EQUALS, 'td a img')
WebUI.waitForElementHasAttribute(button2, 'src', 30)
```

It will return `true` if the img with any source is present. Will wait 30 seconds before giving an error, but you can change it as you wish.